# Can anyone help to find the peak value of histogram using python

Tags: python, image-processing

Can anyone help to find the peak value of histogram  using python...?

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un6ZP.png)

Comment: Hi Aleesha, welcome on SO! To get responses to your question and  for people willing to help you further you will need to show code of what you have do sofar to solve your problem. SO is not a 'write me some code' site. So please, post a [reprex] and you are good to go!

Comment: It's between 0 and 5, isn't it?

Comment: @Aleeshasj you can use `peak = histogram.amax()`, here is the [manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html?highlight=amax#numpy.amax) for using it.